Showing that $\text{curl}(\text{grad}(f)) = 0$ for all $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$.
I am trying to show that $\text{curl}(\text{grad}(f)) = 0$ for all $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$. The set up is that $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold equipped with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$. We have defined
$$\text{curl}(V)(X, Y) = g(\nabla_XV, Y) - g(\nabla_YV, X)
$$
for smooth vector fields $V, X, Y$. Thus, plugging in $\text{grad}(f)$ for $V$, we have
$$\text{curl}(\text{grad}(f))(X, Y) = g(\nabla_X\text{grad}(f), Y) - g(\nabla_Y\text{grad}(f), X)
$$
I believe I need to somehow use the torsion-free property of the Levi-Civita connection. Is this the right way to proceed? Any hints would be appreciated.

The curl you’ve defined ‘artificially’ acts on vector fields $V$ and produces a $2$-form $\text{curl}(V)$ (observe your formula is skew-symmetric in $(X,Y)$). The natural procedure is to define the curl of a $1$-form $\omega$, and as an output a $2$-form. Next, $\text{grad}(f)$ is the vector fields obtained by converting (using $g$) the $1$-form $df$. So, just based on metric-compatibility we see that we have to investigate the expression $\text{curl}(df)$. So, where does torsion-freeness come into play? When we decide to relate $\text{curl}$ with $d$, so as to get $\text{curl}(df)=d(df)=0$.

Let’s be more precise now. I’ll define three curls:

$\text{curl}_g:\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\Omega^2(M)$ defined using the Levi-Civita connection as you did. This eats a vector fields obtained and spits out a $2$-form.
$\text{curl}_{0}:\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2(M)$ defined for any torsion-free connection $\nabla$ on $TM$ (not necessarily Levi-Civita). This eats a $1$-form and spits out a $2$-form by the formula
\begin{align}
(\text{curl}_{0}(\omega))(X,Y):=(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)-(\nabla_Y\omega)(X).
\end{align}
$\text{curl}_{\nabla}:\Omega^1(M)\to \Omega^2(M)$ defined for any connection $\nabla$ on $TM$. This eats a $1$-form and spits out a $2$-form according to the formula
\begin{align}
(\text{curl}_{\nabla}(\omega))(X,Y):=(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)-(\nabla_Y\omega)(X)+\omega(T_{\nabla}(X,Y)),
\end{align}
where $T_{\nabla}$ is the torsion of $\nabla$.

Clearly, $\text{curl}_0$ is a special case of $\text{curl}_{\nabla}$. Now, we have the following easy lemma:

Lemma.
For every $1$-form $\omega$, we have $\text{curl}_{\nabla}(\omega)=d\omega$. In particular, $\text{curl}_{\nabla}$ is a differential operator which is independent of the connection $\nabla$.

The proof is a direct calculation:
\begin{align}
(\text{curl}_{\nabla}(\omega))(X,Y)&:= (\nabla_X\omega)(Y)-(\nabla_Y\omega)(X)+\omega(\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y])\\
&=\bigg((\nabla_X\omega)(Y)+\omega(\nabla_XY)\bigg)-\bigg((\nabla_Y\omega)(X)+\omega(\nabla_YX)\bigg)-\omega([X,Y])\\
&=X\left(\omega(Y)\right)-Y\left(\omega(X)\right)-\omega([X,Y])\\
&=(d\omega)(X,Y),
\end{align}
where in the end we used the coordinate-free definition of the exterior derivative.
Next, by metric-compatibility of the Levi-Civita connection, it is easy to see that for any vector-field $V$, $\text{curl}_g(V)=\text{curl}_0\left(g^{\flat}(V)\right)$, where $g^{\flat}(V):=g(V,\cdot)$ is the $1$-form associated to the vector field $V$. So, if we now plug in $V=\text{grad}_g(f):=g^{\sharp}(df)$ (where $g^{\sharp}$ is the inverse of $g^{\flat}$), then
\begin{align}
\text{curl}_g\left(\text{grad}_g(f)\right)=\text{curl}_0\left(g^{\flat}(g^{\sharp}(df))\right)=\text{curl}_0(df)=d(df)=0.
\end{align}

Of course, you don’t need to invoke any of these ‘abstract’ results. If you just naively use metric-compatibility and the definition $g(\text{grad}(f),X)=Xf$ you can eventually massage the algebra to get
\begin{align}
\text{curl}_g(\text{grad}_g(f))(X,Y)&=\cdots =X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))-[X,Y](f)=0,
\end{align}
the final equal sign by the definition of the Lie bracket.

As a fun exercise, try to generalize the lemma above and establish a formula in the general case, i.e if $\omega$ is a $k$-form and $\nabla$ is any connection on $TM$, give an equation relating $(d\omega)(X_0,\dots, X_k)$ and $(\nabla_{X_i}\omega)$’s (the answer will be a certain alternating sum, plus torsions).

Thank you so much! This was incredibly helpful, and I was able to fill in the details and get the equality. It was very helpful to know that the only things required in our simple case were metric-compatibility and the torsion-free property of the connection. Very much appreciated.
